Create a table in SQL Server with ogr2ogr
I am using ogr2ogr to create a database in SQL Server. It does not consider special characters like dash -.
ogr2ogr --config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS NO --config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_BCP NO -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:driver=ODBC Driver 17 For SQL Server;server=192.168.114.62,1433;database=NiyamGis;uid=GisModelBuilder;pwd=GiSM0delBu1ld3R" -lco SCHEMA=personal -nln "iran-test0-123" '/var/www/html/niyam/pousha/backend/storage/app/gis/uploads/projectionChangednoKUSNEhbhiqPQXKyofYVsYtX5A4plUidAbUpEgQ/iran_railways.shp' iran_railways -nlt POLYGON -lco OVERWRITE=true -t_srs EPSG:4326 2>&1

It creates table iran_test0_123 instead if iran-test0-123.
What should I do to create same table that I want?

I must admit, using hyphens (-) in a object name is a poor idea; it would require the object to be delimit identification each time it's referenced. You're better off with underscores (_) in my opinion.

Yeah.. It seems that ogr2ogr convert hyphens (-) into underline (_) and there is not a way to handle it.

Does it change if you include -lco "launder=no" in your parameters? What happens if you use SQL Server quoting? e.g.: -nln "[iran-test0-123]"

I tried that.. It does not work!

It seems that ogr2ogr converts hyphens (-) into an underscore (_) and there is not a way to handle it.
